# Am I able to send coins to my friends?

Tags: tiny-tower

I wanted to send some coins to my friends in Tiny Tower, am I able to do so? If so how?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Tiny Tower Wiki (Google cache)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:S3ynMIez-uQJ:tinytowerwiki.com/Gifting+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), when you gift stock to a friend that are not able to stock the item you sent at a store, the game will send coins instead.

For example, California rolls are only for the sushi bar.  If your friend does not have a sushi bar, and you send them California rolls, they won't receive the item, instead they'll get their worth in coins.